Retain Numeric Precision Using OBJECT_CONSTRUCT
I have a currency value in a table that I want to include in an OBJECT. The problem is that it looks like Snowflake drops the 2 decimal place precision I want to keep when converting to an OBJECT.
Example:
select to_number('124.00', 18, 2) desired_output, object_construct('my_key', to_number('124.00', 18, 2)) incorrect_output;

DESIRED_OUTPUT  INCORRECT_OUTPUT
124.00  { "my_key": 124 }


DESIRED_OUTPUT  is keeping the precision I want. But as soon as I try to set it as a value in the object, it gets dropped. Is there a way to keep the format without converting it to a VARCHAR?

I submitted a ticket to snowflake support about this and they told me that object_construct "automatically converts numbers to their most compact representation, which means it will drop trailing zeros after the decimal point for integer values." I'm not sure what benefit this has, but the two solutions they gave were either:

Convert the value to a string with TRIM(TO_CHAR(TO_NUMBER(100, 18, 2), '9999999999999999D00'))
Manually construct the json like this SELECT '{"fieldname": ' || TO_NUMBER(100, 18, 2) || '}';

(100 is just used as a static value for reproducing the problem) Number 2 seems like a really hacky solution to me. I ended up going with option 1 since this output is being loaded into opensearch and for some reason, opensearch accepts strings when the field has a type mapping to float even though it doesn't accept integers.

There's a new type on Snowflake: Structured data types

A structured type is an ARRAY, OBJECT, or MAP that contains elements or key-value pairs with specific Snowflake data types. The following are examples of structured types:

An ARRAY of INTEGER elements.
An OBJECT with VARCHAR and NUMBER key-value pairs.
A MAP that associates a VARCHAR key with a DOUBLE value.
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/data-types-structured


However:

Currently, tables other than Iceberg tables do not support structured types. You cannot add a column of a structured type to a regular table.

For normal variants, you can not retain type through them (so the solution is to encode as string)

OBJECT_CONSTRUCT does keep the precision of the source, it's just in your example your data doesn't have any decimal precision: 124 == 124.00
Try this:
select 
to_number('124.00', 18, 2) desired_output1, 
object_construct('my_key', to_number('124.00', 18, 2)) incorrect_output1,
to_number('132.54', 18, 2) desired_output2, 
object_construct('my_key', to_number('132.54', 18, 2)) correct_output2;


Yes, I understand the equivalency. The issue is that this data is being sent to an OpenSearch index which is pretty strict and will complain when integer values are sent into a field defined as a float. Everything is fine when the value in Snowflake is 132.54. The problem is when it's an exact dollar amount.
